# Rivetjs | How to bind image link to style="background-image:url()"

Tags: javascript, html, rivets.js

How i can bind **item.image** to **style="background-image:url()"**

```
<div rv-each-item="items">
   <div style="background-image:url()"></div>
</div>
```

As shown in this [**RIVETS Documentation**](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/)

**One-way binders**

```
rivets.binders.color = function(el, value) {
  el.style.color = value
}

<button rv-color="label.color">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue

```
<div rv-each-item="items">
   <div rv-view-style="item.image"></div>
</div>

**JS**
rivets.binders['view-style'] = function(el, value) {
                el.style = 'background-image:url(https://xxx/' + value + ')';
            }
```